# Passing a SelectList into DropDownListFor via ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the following error when trying to initialize a SelectList with states and display a dropdownlist:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items

Relevant controller code:

```
            var states = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "MO", Text = "Missouri" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "KS", Text = "Kansas" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "AR", Text = "Arkansas" }
            };
            ViewBag.StateList = states;
            return RedirectToAction("Register2", "Account");
```

View code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, new SelectList(ViewBag.StateList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data stored in a ViewBag lasts for a single HTTP request, so it's typically used to pass data from an Action to its View.

When you use `RedirectToAction`, the data in `ViewBag.StateList` is lost.

You can either:
• Create the `states` object inside the `Register2` Action.

• If you can't move the `states` object, you can use `TempData` in place of `ViewBag` and the data will survive the redirect.

```
var states = new List<SelectListItem> {
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "MO", Text = "Missouri" },
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "KS", Text = "Kansas" },
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "AR", Text = "Arkansas" }
};

TempData["StateList"] = states;
```

But you will have to cast it to a list in the view:

```
@{ 
    var states = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)TempData["StateList"];
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, new SelectList(states, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

• A better option is to not rely on ViewBag/ViewData, and instead replace it with a property on your Model class in the Action calling the View:

```
public List<SelectListItem> States{ get; set; }
```

With the View adjusted to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, Model.States, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Given that it's a list of U.S. States, I'm not sure why I hadn't considered initializing it in the HTTPGET of the proper controller action. Thanks!